# D3 multiline chart with dotted segment

Tags: d3.js, charts, linechart

Real life scenario: I need to plot income/expense on a two-line graph, and I need the last month's line to be dotted, to indicate that it's not set in stone yet, and can change. Data and code below, basically followed the Multi-line chart example by mbostock, with two paths.

Now, the problem is making the last segment dotted. I've read about stroke-dasharrays, and thought that would be a sensible idea, but I don't know how to get the last "line" in the path, and every tutorial I've found suggested using lines instead, but I could not for the life of me refactor my code to use lines with my dataset.

Any help, or pointers on refactoring code, would be greatly appreciated! Thanks, guys.

Data looks like this:

```
data =
{
    {
        'type': 'Expense',
        'data': [{ 'date': '201401', 'value': 456 }, {}, ...]
    },
    {
        'type': 'Income',
        'data': [{ 'date': '201401', 'value': 456 }, {}, ...]
    }
}
```

I've used mbostock's tutorials, and my code is follows:

```
function(data)
{
    var self = this;
    this.graphWidth = this.container.width() - 200 - this.margin.left - this.margin.right;
    this.graphHeight = this.graphHeight - this.margin.top - this.margin.bottom;

    this.svg = d3.select('#graphsContainer svg')
            .attr('width', this.graphWidth + this.margin.left + this.margin.right)
            .attr('height', this.graphHeight + this.margin.top + this.margin.bottom)
            .append('g')
            .attr('transform', 'translate(' + this.margin.left + ',' + this.margin.top + ')');

    this.x = d3.time.scale().range([0, this.graphWidth]);
    this.y = d3.scale.linear().range([this.graphHeight, 0]);

    this.xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(this.x).orient('bottom');
    this.yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(this.y).orient('left');

    var parseDate = d3.time.format('%Y%m').parse;

    var line = d3.svg.line()
            .interpolate('basis')
            .x(function(d) { return self.x(d.date); })
            .y(function(d) { return self.y(d.value); });

    data.forEach(function(kv)
    {
        kv.data.forEach(function(d) { d.date = parseDate(d.date); });
    });

    var minX = d3.min(data, function (kv) { return d3.min(kv.data, function (d) { return d.date; }) });
    var maxX = d3.max(data, function (kv) { return d3.max(kv.data, function (d) { return d.date; }) });
    var minY = d3.min(data, function (kv) { return d3.min(kv.data, function (d) { return d.value; }) });
    var maxY = d3.max(data, function (kv) { return d3.max(kv.data, function (d) { return d.value; }) });

    this.x.domain([minX, maxX]);
    this.y.domain([minY, maxY]);

    // x axis
    this.svg.append('g')
            .attr('class', 'x axis')
            .attr('transform', 'translate(0,' + this.graphHeight + ')')
            .call(this.xAxis);

    // y axis
    this.svg.append('g')
            .attr('class', 'y axis')
            .call(this.yAxis);

    var value = this.svg.selectAll('.value')
            .data(data)
            .enter().append('g')
                .attr('class', 'value');

    var path = value.append('path')
            .attr('class', 'line')
            .attr('d', function(d) { return line(d.data); })
            .style('stroke', function(d) { return d.type == 'Income' ? '#006600' : '#CC0000'; });

    value.append('text')
            .datum(function(d)
            {
                return {
                    name: d.type,
                    date: d.data[d.data.length - 1].date,
                    value: d.data[d.data.length - 1].value
                };
            })
            .attr('transform', function(d) { return 'translate(' + self.x(d.date) + ',' + self.y(d.value) + ')'; })
            .attr('x', 3)
            .attr('dy', '.35em')
            .text(function(d) { return d.name; });
    },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Theoretically, there's a way to solve this simply by setting the correct stroke dash-array String. Something like `dash-array: 200 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4;`. These are obviously just sample values, but the idea is to have a really long dash (200 in this example), spanning from the beginning of time till the end of the 2nd-to-last month, and then have a series of dashes (4 4 4...) in the remainder of the path. However, determining where the long dash should end could get tricky. You can use the SVG path method `getTotalLength()` to compute the length of the entire path, and then somehow determine where along this length to transition to dashes (i.e. what "200" should actually equal). Remember, this is length **along the line**, not along the x axis, so determining finding that point needs to account for this, and realistically would only work if the dashed last-month segment is a straight line. You can try it out if you're up for it.

Alternatively, the d3 way would probably be to split up the paths so that instead of 2 you have 4 paths — 2 of which are just the last month's data:

```
    expenses = {
            'type': 'Expense',
            'period': 'past',
            'data': [{ 'date': '201401', 'value': 456 }, {}, ...]
    }

    income = {
            'type': 'Expense',
            'period': 'past',
            'data': [{ 'date': '201401', 'value': 456 }, {}, ...]
    }

    expensesLast = {
            'type': 'Expense',
            'period': 'current',
            'data': [
              expenses.data[expenses.data.length - 2],
              expenses.data.pop()// this ALSO removes the last entry from the array above
            ]
    }

    incomeLast = {
            'type': 'Income'
            'period': 'current',
            'data': [
              income.data[income.data.length - 2],
              income.data.pop()// this ALSO removes the last entry from the array above
            ]
    }

    data = [ expenses, income, expensesLast, incomeLast]
```

With the new `data` at hand, you can draw the lines just like you already do, and then just assign a `stroke-dasharray` depending on what kind of period it is:

```
    var path = value.append('path')
            .attr('class', 'line')
            .attr('d', function(d) { return line(d.data); })
            .style('stroke', function(d) {return d.type == 'Income' ? '#006600' : '#CC0000'; });
            .style('stroke-dasharray', function(d) {
              return d.period == 'current' ? '4 4' : ''; // <--- That!
            });
```

Comment: Many thanks for this, I've chosen to break it into four paths, and managed to get a dotted line. The only issue with it is that the values are nicely interpolated and the line is smooth, except when it changes to the dotted line, it suddenly breaks off and does into a different direction. I guess there's no way to make that into a nice curve?

Comment: Oh yeah, that's a problem when using interpolation. The only workaround I can think of is still using 4 paths, but drawing the entire path in each case -- or at least "more of each path" (i.e. you need the 1 additional next or previous point in each path in order for the interpolation function to know where the path is "going"). This gives you path pairs with full or partial overlaps. Then you can use 4 SVG clipPath to reveal only the relevant parts of each path. Code that creates clipPaths and associates them with paths nodes can get a bit busy, but it's not too bad.

Comment: It's also possible to do the above with just 2 clip paths, if you first create 2 groups — one containing the 2 "past" paths and the other containing the 2 "present" paths (still with the overlap I described in the previous comment). Then each of the 2 groups gets clipped by a clipPath. This is possible since the switch from past to present happens at the same x-position for all paths.